# Why are there two Utsu-tsus?

Tags: gatchaman-crowds

In episode 2, there's a scene with Utsu-tsu cleaning the Tachikawa City International Greenery Garden where she volunteers. However, the scene is a bit strange, as it shows two of her in the same shot:

[image]

As far as I can tell, both of the people in the shot are Utsu-tsu. She's also in the two shots before this one, and doesn't seem to move between them, so there could be more than two of her.

**Why are there two Utsu-tsus here? Is she able to double her body, or does she have clones, or are they imposters, or something else?**

Comment: It might be to show a passage of time. Sometimes they show that (if both things take place at the same place) by showing the person doing different activities at the same time.

Comment: @kuwaly I do not think that is the case here given how the scene is depicted, but you may be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In episode 4, it is revealed that Utsu-tsu has the ability to create copies of her body as one of her powers as a Gatchaman. It seems there are other modifications to her body as well, though these have not yet been completely explained. Her copying ability allows her to perform basic functions, but it seems that conversing and interacting with others is difficult through the copies. She uses this ability to simultaneously follow Hajime and O.D.

Here's a gif of her making a copy:

[image]

It's probably worth a mention that the opening theme actually foreshadowed this before the scene in the question:

[image]

Comment: But it seems like when she makes a copy she goes into loli-sized mode. In the park sweeping shot, she seems to be full-sized.

Comment: @Krazer She seemed to be full-sized talking to both Hajime and O.D. at the same time with two different bodies in one of the later scenes in the episode. I'm pretty sure the copies are all normal sized, unless I was really misinterpreting those scenes.

Comment: Odd, she seems taller in the image in the question...